# Adding and Additional Series to a Plot after a Mouse Click using R HIghcharter Library

Tags: r, shiny, r-highcharter

I need to be able to add another trace to a plot after a mouse click. I am using R's web framework Shiny to display the plot in a web browser. The series I want to add is dots or any series at this point.

I need to draw lines on the plot also. I want to click a starting point and a ending and a line pass through the clicked points.

This is what I have so far.

```
#############To Update
#if (!require("devtools"))
#install.packages("devtools")
#devtools::install_github("jbkunst/highcharter")

library("shiny")
library("highcharter")

dots<-hc_add_series_scatter(cars$speed, cars$dist)

hc_base <- highchart() %>% 
  hc_xAxis(categories = citytemp$month) %>% 
  hc_add_series(name = "Tokyo", data = citytemp$tokyo) 

ui <- fluidPage(
  h2("Viewer"),
  fluidRow(
    h3(""), highchartOutput("hc_1", width = "100%", height = "800px"),
     h3("Click"), verbatimTextOutput("hc_1_input2")
  )
)
server = function(input, output) {
  output$hc_1 <- renderHighchart({
       hc_base %>% 
          hc_add_theme(hc_theme_ffx())%>%
                 hc_tooltip(backgroundColor="skyblue",crosshairs = TRUE, borderWidth = 5, valueDecimals=2)%>%
                      hc_add_event_series(series="dots", event = "click")
})
output$hc_1_input2 <- renderPrint({input$hc_1_click })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: it throws an error for me: `> dots<-hc_add_series_scatter(cars$speed, cars$dist)
Error: is.highchart(x = hc) is not TRUE`

Answer (score 2):

This could be one way of doing it:

```
library(shiny)
library(highcharter)


hc_base <- highchart() %>% 
  hc_xAxis(categories = citytemp$month) %>% 
  hc_add_series(name = "Tokyo", data = citytemp$tokyo) 

ui <- fluidPage(
  h2("Viewer"),
  fluidRow(
    h3(""), highchartOutput("hc_1", width = "100%", height = "800px"),
    h3("Click"), verbatimTextOutput("hc_1_input2")
  )
)
server = function(input, output) {
  output$hc_1 <- renderHighchart({
    hc_base %>% 
      hc_add_theme(hc_theme_ffx())%>%
      hc_tooltip(backgroundColor="skyblue",crosshairs = TRUE, borderWidth = 5, valueDecimals=2)%>%
      hc_add_event_point(event = "click")
  })

  observeEvent(input$hc_1_click,{
    output$hc_1 <- renderHighchart({
      hc_base %>% 
        hc_add_theme(hc_theme_ffx())%>%
        hc_tooltip(backgroundColor="skyblue",crosshairs = TRUE, borderWidth = 5, valueDecimals=2)%>%
        hc_add_series_scatter(cars$speed, cars$dist)
    })

  })

  output$hc_1_input2 <- renderPrint({input$hc_1_click })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: this is really nice work. Any idea how to implement a button to go back to the initial state without refreshing the page? 
Many thanks.

Comment: @GabrielOana, you could add a button to reset the plot while rendering the second plot.